# Command to launch visual studio code not recognized on windows 8.1

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have installed Visual Studio Code on my Windows 8.1 PC. After installing it launches correctly. When I try to launch from the command prompt with "code .", I get a prompt that the command isn't recognized.

Comment: What is the specific command you are trying to execute from the command prompt? Are you in the right directory? Do you have the path to the file in your system path?

Comment: Try typing `where code` and check whether it was found. It should be under `AppData\Local\Code\bin\code.cmd`

Comment: I enter the standard command to open a directory in visual code: "code .".

Answer (score 1):

If you install VS Code through the setup, this code.cmd will be placed automatically in `C:\Users\<your name>\AppData\Local\Code\bin`. Please verify that the command is there!